# Postman: Pop-up login modal for authentication

Tags: postman

Postman now has support for Oauth2.0. The nice thing is that if necessary, Postman will display a pop-up login modal for authentication if the Auth URL redirects to a login screen.

My question: is it possible to display this same modal for a request via a script? I would like to replicate the same Oauth flow via a script (instead of having to generate an access token via the button).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can get this done. Instead of having a button create a modal dialog using javascript and get username and password from the dialog and poss them to the oauth request to get the token. I believe you are using password credentials grant where you need to send username and password while making a request.